# Not able to apt-get update from terminal, what to do now?

Tags: linux, apt-get

Whenever I try to update from terminal, I get this error:

```
root@Utkarsh[utkarsh]#apt-get update
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha Release
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Sources
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Sources
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Sources
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main i386 Packages
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Few suggestions: If you are logging in as root all the time, STOP. Create a non-root account and use `sudo`(never mind if you just used `su` for this post). Try to use `aptitude` in place of `apt-get`.
When you are saying "Not able to apt-get update from terminal" clearly state what you are expecting it to do. Also, this is not a good title for this post. You should use something like "Unable to update my system". Current title doesn't tell what is your actual problem.

Comment: @khajvah I am just 13, how will i know this all? I dont know anything about linux! and also, am i too much small to do this all?

Comment: I am happy you chose Linux. Welcome to the club ;) You are not small. Opinion like that about yourself won't take you far. You can do anything. I am 18 years old programmer and I regret that I didn't start learning from your age(because I thought like you). Important thing is believing in yourself. Read tutorials online. I just found a [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_02_02.html) but you can find more and better tutorials by googling yourself. If you really want to learn, forget how old are you, surf the web, read a lot, break and fix your system.

Comment: Just few things that I mentioned in first comment: [Users](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups), [aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)), [package management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) and [sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.bosslinux.in/boss/ anokha/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.bosslinux.in_boss_dists_anokha_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

That's not an error. It's just a warning.

You can remove the duplicate entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` if you want, but it is not necessary. For a much more specific answer, see: [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Comment: now, what must i do? please help me  i am just 13 year old

Comment: You don't have to do anything. As I mentioned, you *can* remove duplicate entries in the `sources.list` file. But if you're unsure or don't know what you're doing editing that file, I'd rather leave it as it is.

Comment: IF, I WILL LEAVE AS IT IS, THEN HOW WILL I UPDATE?

Comment: You already *did* the update. Since there is no error in the command (anything prefixed with `E:`), it ran successfully. It finished with `Reading package lists... Done.` You may now do an `apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the packages. (And please, don't use ALL CAPS, that's really not nice.)

Comment: i will reply you after the upgrade. sorry for waiting! and thanks for information i will not use all caps

Comment: okay everything worked fine, i actually not waited at that time!

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get update` is behaving normally. Those are warnings. Notice the `W:`s in front of the lines?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do) is what `apt-get update` does

If you want to update your system (packages that you have installed using apt-get), use `apt-get upgrade`.

Additionally, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) apt tutorial.